# How to have multiple Kafka brokers replication

Tags: apache-kafka, kafkajs

So I'm new to kafka, and I have trouble finding informations on having multiple kafka instances in order to have my message service still up if a broker instance goes down.

I've made a little local demo with Kafka JS and I've seen that we declare our brokers with an array like

```
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['localhost:9092']
})
```

So my question is how to have X instances of my kafka broker that are synchronised trough messages but using different storages / instances / server (not sure what the appropriate word is here) ?

Many thanks !
Kev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a Kafka cluster. There is no short answer on how to do it. I recommend you to look for an article on how to do it. For example this one: [How to Setup a Kafka Cluster](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-setup-kafka-cluster)